# How to increase the id in frontend

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs

I am having a component screen and in that component, there is + and - buttons are to add a new row and remove existing row.
For this, I am generating one id in the front end like initially

```
$scope.document = [{
    'Name': "",
    'mandatory': "false",
    'id': 1,
    "status": "1"
}];
```

when clicking on add(+) button then I am increasing the id like below

```
$scope.addDynamicRow = function() {
    $scope.document.push({
        'Name': "",
        'mandatory': "false",
        'id': $scope.document[$scope.document.length - 1].id + 1,
        "status": "1"
    });
};
```

this id is working fine and I am able to get the details based on its id.

There is no delete option in my project, so I will change the status to 2 when clicking on specific record based on the index
and I will get the details from DB with condition status =1.

the problem is when click on the last record remove(-) then it will be changed to status 2 and let us assume id is 3 then I will hide the records with ng-if in the jsp, then I will click on the plus(+) button of the above record then it will also create the same id like 3. So in the database with the same 3 there will be 2 records. Here I am getting the clash. I want to increase the id without duplicating.

Comment: yes, because you are not getting record which status is 2. so your $scope.document.length will remain same as your last record.

Comment: How are you fetching records from db based on id?

Comment: @GiteshPurbia yes, but I want a suggestion to overcome this issue

Comment: @Bharadwaj yes I am getting based on id

Comment: Your backend should create and manage your IDs, not your client. This is a logic problem.

Comment: you get all records from database, and don't display to view whose status is 2, if are are generating id by array length or you can generate id from backend (server side).

Comment: if you want to create `id` in js, then write a function which returns id by iterating through the existing array and adding one number to the highest value. This link may help you, https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/prototype

Comment: @user9130953 You are thinking as you will have only one user using this application. Id creation should always be handles in backend.

Comment: Yes, use auto incremented field in your DB as id

Comment: yes, I have maintained id from backend and it is working fine.